# d-dimensional topological manifold example

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

I am having trouble understanding the concepts of manifolds, so I recently watched these two videos on the topic [topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G4SqIboeig&t=2s)  [manifolds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93f-ayezCqE).

During watching I came up with the following example, for which I will briefly denote the required definitions I am trying to grasp first.

The definition in question given for a *$d$-dimensional topological manifold* is:

**Definition**: A topological space $(M, \mathcal{O})$ is called a *d-dimensional topological manifold*, if 
$$ \forall p \in M : \exists \mathcal{U} \in \mathcal{O} : \exists x : \mathcal{U} \to x(\mathcal{U}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d,$$ such that

1. $x$ is invertible: $x^{-1} : x(\mathcal{U}) \to \mathcal{U}$
2. $x$ is continuous
3. $x^{-1}$ is continuous

**Note 1**: In the forall condition, it is implicitly required that $p \in \mathcal{U}$.

In the video lecture, the definition for continuity is also given:

**Definition**: Let $(M, \mathcal{O}_M)$ and $(N, \mathcal{O}_N)$ be topological spaces. Then a map $f: M\to N$ is called continuous (w.r.t $\mathcal{O}_M$ and $\mathcal{O}_N$), if
$$ \forall V \in \mathcal{O}_N : \operatorname{preim}_f(V) \in \mathcal{O}_M.$$

**My own example**:
Let the set considered be $M = \{1, 2\}$. Of course it can be shown (and indeed it has been in the first video mentioned) that $$\mathcal{O}_M := \left\{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\right\}$$ is a topology on $M$. So $(M, \mathcal{O}_M)$ is a topological space.

For $\mathbb{R}^d$ we have the *standard topology* $\mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$ of open balls. Since I am investigating maps $x : \mathcal{U} \to x(\mathcal{U}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, I believe I should inherit a topology for $x(\mathcal{U})$ from $\mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$, which would be
$$ \mathcal{O}_\text{standard}|_{x(\mathcal{U})} := \left\{ \mathcal{V} \cap x(\mathcal{U}) | \mathcal{V} \in \mathcal{O}_\text{standard} \right\}.$$
Thus the inherited topology can be directly calculated to be 
$$ \mathcal{O}_\text{standard}|_{x(\mathcal{U})} = \left\{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\right\}$$
for my example.

To determine that it is a 1-dimensional topological manifold, I investigate for each $p$ in the given set $M$:

- $p=1$: pick $\mathcal{U} \in \mathcal{O}_m$ with $p \in \mathcal{U}$ to be $\mathcal{U} = {1, 2}$ and the map $x : \mathcal{U} \to x(\mathcal{U}) = \operatorname{id}$, where obviously $x(\mathcal{U}) = {1, 2}$. Of course the identity operator is invertible, so the first condition of the definition above is met. Next, I calculate all the preimages of  $\mathcal{O}_\text{standard}|_{x(\mathcal{U})}$, which happen to be

  - $\operatorname{preim}_x(\emptyset) = \emptyset \in \mathcal{O}_m$
  - $\operatorname{preim}_x(\{1\}) = \{1\} \in \mathcal{O}_m$
  - $\operatorname{preim}_x(\{2\}) = \{2\} \in \mathcal{O}_m$
  - $\operatorname{preim}_x(\{1, 2\}) = \{1, 2\} \in \mathcal{O}_m$

  to conclude $x$ is a continuous map from $(U, \mathcal{O}_M|_\mathcal{U})$ to $(x(\mathcal{U}), \mathcal{O}_\text{standard}|_{x(\mathcal{U})})$. Lastly , since the domain and the target space are identical for this example and $\operatorname{id}$ is its own inverse, nothing about the preimages will change and I conclude $x^{-1}$ is continuous, too.
- $p = 2$: With the same choice of $\mathcal{U}$ and $x$ valid, I conclude $x$ is also an invertible, continuous and $x^{-1}$ a continuous map.

Consequently, $(M, \mathcal{O}_M)$ must be a 1-dimensional topological manifold.

**Is this reasoning correct?
And: If I had taken $d\in \mathcal{N}$ other than 1, with $x \mapsto (x, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and $x^{-1} \mapsto x(1)$, could I have reasoned that $(M, \mathcal{O}_M)$ is any d-dimensional topological manifold?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you must feel that this is not correct. Because you would get a manifold that is simultaneously $1,2,3,\ldots$ etc. dimensional. This surely doesn't sound right. In fact we know that if $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold then **it is not** a $m$-dimensional manifold for $n\neq m$.

And indeed, there is a gap in your reasoning. The very important and missing ingredient in your definition of a manifold is that $x(\mathcal{U})$ has to be **an open** subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (without a loss of generality you can even assume that $x(\mathcal{U})=\mathbb{R}^d$). A finite set of singletons is not an open subset in any $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d\geq 1$. A singleton is open only in $\mathbb{R}^0$ (understood as a singleton $\mathbb{R}^0=\{0\}$ itself) making your $M$ a $0$-dimensional (disconnected) manifold.

Also note that you implicitely assumed that $x:\mathcal{U}\to\mathbb{R}^d$ is given by $x(1)=1$ and $x(2)=2$. Why not $x(1)=7$ and $x(2)=\pi$? What I'm saying is that you didn't define what $x$ is.

The rest seems to be correct. Good job in dealing with details. Don't take things for granted, always check yourself if possible.

Comment: To add to this answer, $M$ _is_ a 0-dimensional (albeit disconnected) manifold, because your singleton would be open in $\mathbb{R}^0$ which is a point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have to think about it some more, but I believe I will have questions later. You were right about my intuition of this being somehow wrong, since it seemed to easy and too ambiguous.
I have seen similar definitions of manifolds to what I gave above, but instead with a map $x: \mathcal{U} \to W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$. Following your advice, I can always require that $W\in\mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$, i.e. it is open. Then I still take the map $1\mapsto 1$ and $2\mapsto 2$. For all other elements $w\in W$ with $w\neq\{1, 2\}$, the preimage is $\emptyset$.

Comment: And the same reasoning would have me conclude it still could be any d-dimensional topological manifold. Wouldn't I have to require that $W$ is in fact the image of $\mathcal{U}$ under $x$ **and** $W\in \mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$?

Comment: @marc Since you (correctly) assume that $x$ is invertible then in particular $x$ is "onto" (surjective), i.e. $W$ is automatically an image of $\mathcal{U}$. So your example is now broken because the codomain is bigger then it was and so $x$ is no longer invertible.

Comment: @freakish Okay, that clarified a lot. Thinking about this (somewhat hidden) implication, is there really any need to edit the initially given definition? I mean, condition (3) can only be satisfied, if $x(\mathcal{U}) \in \mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$: Let $x^{-1}: x(\mathcal{U})\to \mathcal{U}$ continuous. Then $\operatorname{preim}_{x^{-1}}(\mathcal{U}) = x(\mathcal{U}) \in \mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$. So ultimately, I think the definition given was correct, but slighly obscure. Did I get this correctly?
Considering my example, $x(\mathcal{U})$ must be choosen "larger" ro be open, but ...

Comment: ... then $x$ will not be invertible to the set of singletons of my example.

Comment: No, condition (3) does not imply that $x(\mathcal{U})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Condition (3) implies that $x(\mathcal{U})$ is open in **itself**. Which is trivially true. Just like your original example: $x(1)=1$ and $x(2)=2$. The image is $\{1,2\}$ and $x$ **is** invertible as a function to image $x(\mathcal{U})$. But the image **is not** open in $\mathbb{R}^d$. You need that additional assumption.

Comment: Note that conditions (1)-(3) don't care about anything outside of $x(\mathcal{U})$. Thus you need the additional assumption on the relationship between $x(\mathcal{U})$ and $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @freakish I did never mean to say "implies". What I showed was, that for condition (3) to hold, it is necessary to have $x(\mathcal{U})\in \mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$, since $\mathcal{U}$ is open by premise, $x^{-1}$ is continuous by requirement and continuity is essentially "preimages of open sets are open". So what I meant to say is: the requirement for $x(\mathcal{U})$ to be an open set w.r.t $\mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$ is implicitly there. And I understand how my example fails to meet this condition.

Comment: @marc No the requirement **is not there**. For condition (3) to hold you need $x(\mathcal{U})$ is open in $x(\mathcal{U})$. So not $x(\mathcal{U})\in\mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$ but $x(\mathcal{U})\in\mathcal{O}_\text{standard}|_{x(\mathcal{U})}$. Look at the domain of $x^{-1}$. It is not $\mathbb{R}$. It is $x(\mathcal{U})$, so the topology is relative to $x(\mathcal{U})$. This **does not** mean that $x(\mathcal{U})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Look at the same example again. Let $M=\{1,2\}$, $A=\{1,2\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. I assume both $M,A$ inherit topology from $\mathbb{R}$, meaning they are discrete (every subset is open). Let $f:M\to A$ be given by $f(x)=x$. This function is **clearly** continuous and invertible. The inverse $g:A\to M$ is given by $g(x)=x$ which is continuous as well. But $A$ **is not** open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also usually we call this $x$ function **a chart** and a collection of charts **an atlas**. You may want to read this as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)#Charts

Comment: @freakish Okay. got it. Unfortunately there was this [very misleading part](https://youtu.be/93f-ayezCqE?t=9m18s) of the lecture, where I got the incomplete definition from. So basically I assume I have to require as you said the target of the chart to be $x(\mathcal{U}) = W\in \mathcal{O}_\text{standard}$, which makes intuitively sense when working with continuity in real spaces, as it gives the known "neighbourhoods" of elements. Of course this might add a number of points to the target set, but then their preimages are the empty set.

Comment: @freakish Then considering our example at hand, the reverse map $x^{-1}: W\to \mathcal{U}: p \mapsto p$ is clearly not continuous on $M$ and thus my calculations couldn't show $(M, \mathcal{O}_M)$ to be a n-dimensional manifold for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. As a sidenote, I am fully aware that my failure to show it being a manifold doesn't disqualify it from being one, regardless.